# Measuring viral coefficient if sharing source is through facebook or twitter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

So the standard way of measuring the viral coefficient is via email addresses i.e. current user xyz@xyz.com invites 10 people via email so that you have their email addresses and can tell how many signed up and can therefore calculate the viral coefficient.

How would you calculate and program for the viral coefficient if the current user xyz@xyz.com shares a link on your page to facebook or twitter because you wouldn't know how many people they have invited or have their email addresses.  Even if you put an estimate of say 100 people referred to your site, how would you know if the new user was referred from user xyz@xyz.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give every user a custom link like : `example.com/register?refer=foobar`

Whenever anyone registers, look for the GET parameter `refer` and you will know who referred this new user.

Comment: Great, thanks.  So now I know who has referred the user I need to know if that referred user actually signs up.  So with regards to recording the event that they have clicked on "register", would you use google event tracking to track that using foobar as a variable or would you use something else

Comment: When they get to example.com/register, I would grab foobar and put the value in a hidden field in the registration form. When they submit the form, check the value again. At this point, you can be sure they have registered